# How to compare datetime in Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-views

Suppose I have:

```
ds = datetime.datetime.now
dd = Entry.objects.get(pk=id).pub_date
```

How to compare 2 objects above? I want to get the time difference between them.
Please help me solve this problem. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I am assuming that `pub_date` is a `django.db.models.DateField`, which means you can treat it as a `datetime.date` object.

If you convert them to the same type (either `datetime.datetime` or `datetime.date`) and  subtract one from the other, you will get an instance of `datetime.timedelta`.

As you are using `datetime.datetime.now()`, if your `pub_date` is simply a date rather than a datetime, you may as well use `ds = datetime.date.today()` instead:

```
>>> ds = datetime.date.today()
>>> dd = datetime.date(2009, 12, 9)
>>> ds - dd
datetime.timedelta(2) # 2 days ago
```