# Comparing two dates in Django

Tags: python, django

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to compare datetime in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887354/how-to-compare-datetime-in-django)

I need to compare 2 dates

> object.submit_date.ctime() > user.last_login.ctime()

but always get false.

no matter whether  last_login it is after the last  submit_date

Answer (score 9, accepted):

are comparing wrong, you have to use date() or isoformat() instead of ctime()

Like this:

> object.submit_date.isoformat() > user.last_login.isoformat()

this includes the time

or

> object.submit_date.date() > user.last_login.date()

Answer (score 3):

If its a `datetime` object. you can simply compare the datetime ojects rather than using ctime.

```
>>> a =datetime.now()
>>> b = datetime.now()
>>> a>b
False
>>> b>a
True
```

Comment: simple, yet the most effective manner of doing it